# Is there a better way to troubleshoot sending messages to Rumble Chat

Tags: chatbot, rumble-api

Let me just say up front, I'm a complete amateur at coding. I'm creating my own chat bot for Rumble and I'm running into a wall with my script sending the command response back to the chat. I have it so it listens to the chat and provides the command response to say a command like '!merch' but gives the error below using some print commands to trying to troubleshoot.

Here's the response from the server I'm trying to send to:(identifiers hidden with ***)

```
Received event: {'request_id': '8+wOEkAWFinfBP3KTtso+XKCbovAN1CL2tlNLThyggU', 'type': 'messages', 'data': {'messages': [{'id': '*******', 'time': '2024-02-23T05:36:47+00:00', 'user_id': '*******', 'text': '!merch', 'blocks': [{'type': 'text.1', 'data': {'text': '!merch'}}]}], 'users': [{'id': '******', 'username': '******', 'link': '/user/*******', 'is_follower': True, 'color': '#f54fd1', 'badges': ['moderator']}], 'channels': [[]]}}
```

And here's the error response:

```
Error sending message: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: https://web7.rumble.com/chat/api/chat/{chat_id}/stream
Response status code: 500
Response content: <html>
<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I've got the payload set correctly as far as the format of:

```
payload = {
            "type": "messages",
            "messages": [
                {
                    "text": [message]
                }
            ]
        }
```

Just wondering if there's any other troubleshooting that I haven't thought of.

I've tried different payload formats and double checking that the url is correct but to no avail

Comment: Why not check the server's error log for this? It's usual that internal details of such an error are not provided through the response itself

Comment: 500 is intended not to leak information to the client. The only way to determine the cause is to inspect server logs.